# Iteration with for loop using round returns "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, rounding

I have a huge `df` that looks like this:

| date | stock1 | stock2 | stock3 | stock4 | stock5 | stock6 | stock7 | stock8 | stock9 | stock10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/20 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 11/20 | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.1 |
| 12/20 | 0.3 | 0.6 | 0.9 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.7 | 0.9 | 0.1 |

I want to find, for each row, the 20% higher values of stocks and the 20% lower. The output should be:

| date | higher | lower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/20 | stock9, stock 10 | stock1, stock 2 |
| 11/20 | stock1, stock 2 | stock8, stock 10 |
| 12/20 | stock3, stock 9 | stock1, stock 10 |

My code looks now like this:

```
l= df.count(1)
rank = pd.DataFrame()
for i in len(l):
      rank[i, "winners"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(round(l[i-1]*0.2).index.tolist(), axis=1)
      rank[i, "losers"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(round(l[i-1]*0.2).index.tolist(), axis=1)
```

and I get the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable". I have checked the dtype of l: Freq: M, Length: 344, dtype: float64.
What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: There is typo `df(lambda x: `, need `df.apply(lambda x: `

Comment: I just saw I and corrected in the post. The typo was not in my correct, though.

Comment: range(len(l))...

Comment: Same error as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'stock1':range(10), 'stock2':range(10,20), 'stock3':range(10,20), 'stock4':range(10,20), 'stock5':range(50,60)})

colnum = int(.2*len(df.columns))
df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(colnum).index.tolist(), axis=1)
```

input df:

[image]

output:

[image]

Based on your comment:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({f'stock{i}':np.random.randint(1,10,10) for i in range(2000)})
colnum = int(.2*len(df.columns))
df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(colnum).index.tolist(), axis=1)
```

input df with 2000 columns:

[image]

output:

[image]

Based on the other comment, with possible nans:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({f'stock{i}':np.random.randint(1,10,10) for i in 

range(10)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({f'stock{i}':np.random.randint(1,10,1) for i in range(7)})
df3 = df.append(df2)
df3 = df3.astype(np.float64)
df3.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(int(.2*np.sum([1 for y in x if not np.isnan(y)]))).index.tolist(), axis=1)
```

input df:

[image]

output:

[image]

a little bit better:

```
df3.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(int(.2*x.notna().sum())).index.tolist(), axis=1)
```

Comment: I have more than 2000 stocks in my real dataset, so I cannnot apply that.

Comment: Why you can not? what is the problem?

Comment: In the first line of the suggested code, I have to write down the name of each stock. In addition, I need to have 2 columns in my output df ("winners" and "losers").

Comment: For the first problem you mentioned: It is just an example. you do not need to do the first line becaues you have the df beforehand. for the second one, just repeat the last line with nsmallest.

Comment: In the code, for every series in the output we will have "colnum" stocks in the output. But this is not what I need. In my original dataset, the number of observations per row of the df is difference one from another. So, for example, a row with 100 obs, will have 20 obs in the output (0.2*100). A row with 150 obs will have 30 obs in the output. That is the reason why I am using the for-loop.

Comment: Yo mean that some rows have empty cells? can you show example?

Comment: Yes. Many cells are empty, due to missing value (NaN). To have an example, you can just set some values from your sample dataset as "nan".

Comment: I will handle that.

Comment: see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new columns:

```
df1 = df.set_index('date')
i= int(round(len(df1.columns)*0.2))

df1 = df1.assign(winners = df1.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(i).index.tolist(), axis=1),
                 losers = df1.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(i).index.tolist(), axis=1))
     
rank = df1[['winners','losers']].reset_index()                             
print (rank)
    date            winners             losers
0  10/20  [stock9, stock10]   [stock1, stock2]
1  11/20   [stock2, stock1]  [stock10, stock8]
2  12/20   [stock3, stock9]  [stock10, stock1]
```